# Stand Alone Accounting Systems vs ERP with Finance Module

Tags: finance, accounting

We are replacing our finance package which is currently tied into our name brand CRM. It isn't meeting our needs is the short of it. We want to use a SaaS solution. Right now Netsuite for example is on our short list with their core finance/accounting module activated.

However one question I have is, does it make sense to use a software system specific to finance/accounting instead of an ERP with a finance module? Would it be any cheaper or more expensive. Would one be more flexible than the other? To be truthful, I don't know of any SaaS based financial software other than the names Sage and Quickbooks, but I am certain these would not be able to handle the work we require. Any ideas and insight are welecome.

For what it's worth, we will be purchasing a standalone SaaS based billing system to integrate with the CRM and financials software (whatever the latter will be).